# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000002 on UITableView reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access, crashlytics

I've had this problem for a while and it's driving me nuts.  This is reported by Crashlytics but only for a few users. I'm unable to recreate the problem myself.

I'm using a SplitViewController and this occurs after a user adds data within a UIViewController and touch the save button, which then returns to the SplitViewController to perform the method 'saveItemEntry' shown below.

I've tried a suggestion from a previous post which was to wrap the [self.tableView reloadData] with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void), but that actually made it worse. It isn't like the data takes ages to load, it doesn't, so I can't see that multi-tasking will help, but I'm open to advice on whether I should be doing that.

I'm really not clear on how to interperupt the crash info. If someone can and can suggest what might be causing this that would be awesome.

If more info is needed please let me know.

Here's the crash details:
[image]

Here's the Raw stuff..

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x20407ae2 objc_msgSend + 1
1  CoreFoundation                 0x20b8391b -[NSDictionary    descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 310
2  Foundation                     0x2136fe2d _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 60
3  CoreFoundation                 0x20c011a3 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 7986
4  CoreFoundation                 0x20bff255 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 80
5  CoreFoundation                 0x20c17559 _CFLogvEx2 + 96
6  CoreFoundation                 0x20c179af _CFLogvEx3 + 118
7  Foundation                     0x214374f7 _NSLogv + 126
8  Foundation                     0x2137e79d NSLog + 28
9  UIKit                          0x24eac5fb -[UITableView reloadData] + 1818
10 Simple Meeting Minutes         0xfb859 -[MMDetailTableVC saveItemEntry:] (MMDetailTableVC.m:1423)
11 Simple Meeting Minutes         0x10becf -[MMItemViewController saveButtonAction:] (MMItemViewController.m:526)
12 UIKit                          0x24dfd771 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
13 UIKit                          0x24f7ec71 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 140
14 UIKit                          0x24dfd771 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
15 UIKit                          0x24dfd701 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 64
16 UIKit                          0x24de561f -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 446
17 UIKit                          0x24de574b -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 746
18 UIKit                          0x24dfd051 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 616
19 UIKit                          0x24dfccbf -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 646
20 UIKit                          0x24df55d7 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 642
21 UIKit                          0x24dc6119 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 204
22 UIKit                          0x24dc4757 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5134
23 CoreFoundation                 0x20bf1257 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
24 CoreFoundation                 0x20bf0e47 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
25 CoreFoundation                 0x20bef1af __CFRunLoopRun + 806
26 CoreFoundation                 0x20b41bb9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
27 CoreFoundation                 0x20b419ad CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
28 GraphicsServices               0x21dbbaf9 GSEventRunModal + 160
29 UIKit                          0x24e2dfb5 UIApplicationMain + 144
30 Simple Meeting Minutes         0xf5d6f main (main.m:16)
31 libdispatch.dylib              0x207f4873 (Missing)
```

and here's my code in this particular area..

```
- (void)saveItemEntry:(MMitem *)item{

    if (item)
    {
        // save item to the sqlite3 database file
        NSString *resultStr = [self.meetingModel saveItem:item];

        if ([resultStr isEqualToString:@"OK"])
        {
            // all good so close form and refresh data

            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
            [self.tableView reloadData];

            // or if there is an error result then display message
        }
        else if ([resultStr isEqualToString:@"DescriptionNotesMissing"])
        {
            [self showAlert:@"Missing Description or Notes" :@"An Item Description or Notes is required" :0];
            [self.itemViewController.itemDescription becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        // for any other error do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: In Crashlytics it's specifying that the crash occurred in line no. 1423 for MMDetailTableVC.m for method name saveItemEntry: Can you specify what is present in line no. 1423?

Comment: Hi Varun, thanks for looking at this.  Line 1423 has [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: I have a suggestion. Do not dismiss the controller and reload the data at the same time. I think this might be causing the issue. The data might have been deallocated while the tableView is reloading the data. So either reload the tableView or dismiss the controller.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  To give some background.  The app uses a SplitViewControler.  When the user taps on an item in the DetailTableView, or taps the 'Add Item' button, it opens another view controller to either edit the item or to add an item.  When they are done and tap the 'Save' button the saveItemEntry method in the detailTable View controller is called as a delegate protocol method from the ItemViewController.

Comment: This method then calls the saveItem method in the meetingModel to save the item to the sqllite database.  I then need to dismiss the Item View Controller and reload the tableview.   The reload data then reads in the data from the sqlite database to a mutable array and refreshed the table from the array.   I don't see how I can leave either the dismiss view controller or the reloadData out.  Do I need a delay or do I need to change the order, reload before the dismiss perhaps?

Comment: You have to write the dismiss controller code in ItemViewController after calling the delegate method.

Comment: The ItemViewController is the child vc, I understand best practice Is to only dismissed it from the parent vc, which is the detailTableView of the split view controller.